# Find the postion of SNP in the gen list

Tags: perl, sequence, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, bioperl

I have SNP data and gen list data. I am looking for the position of SNP cotain in the gen list data when I compare with gen list. For example:

1. The SNP data :

   ```
   Pos_start pos_end 
   14185     14185      
   ....      .....
   ```
2. The gen list data:

   ```
   5"side(pos_start)  3"sile(pos_end)
     1                  1527      
     1920               1777 
     ....               .....
   ```
3. the result: in the position 14185 of SNP contain at the 16185 position of the gen list.

Below is my code but it has some problem in sort the number.

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl -w

   open(POS1,"<posi1.txt"); (I collect two data and save with posi1.txt) 
    @posi1=<POS1>;
   open(list,">list.txt");
   @list1=@posi1;
   @list2= sort num_last (@list1);
   $list2 = join( '', @list2);

   print $list2;
   print list $list2."\n\n";
   close(list);
  sub num_last {
my ($num_a, $num_b);
$num_a=$a=~ /＾[0-9]/;
$num_b=$b=~ /＾[0-9]/;
if ($num_a && $num_b){
    return $a<=>$b;
} elsif ($num_a){
    return 1;
} elsif ($num_b){
    return -1;
} else {
    return $a cmp $b;
}
      }
```

I would appreciate if you could give some pointers.

Comment: The question is unclear. I can't tell the answer to `in the position 14185 of SNP contain at the (??) position of the gen list.` from the example, so I can't understand the desired result. Could you please further explain what do you expect. We are no bionformatics (at least not everyone), so you might need to explain some obvious things

Comment: at the position start of SNP 14185 I don"t know it contain in the gen list or not so I looking for that position containd in the gen list and the position at the gen.
for example: in position of SNP 14185 is T.

Comment: That clarifies nothing. Ask right question, get right answer. The question is not `right` now. What's SNP? How `SNP` data is connected to `gen` list in your sample? What `genotype`, `reference` mean? `initiation condon` is the [start codon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_codon) of the gene, I presume? Does `5"side` and `3"side` relevant to the task?

Comment: SNP:A single-nucleotide polymorphism (SNP, pronounced snip). genotype and refrence is not important in this problem. For example, two sequenced DNA fragments from different individuals, AAGCCTA to AAGCTTA, contain a difference in a single nucleotide.
5"side and 3"side same with Pos_start pos_end.And my problem is with the positions of SNP where the position of the gen.

Comment: Could you please remove irrelevant information from your question, it's still hard to tell what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sort sub does not operate on values you pass. It should be something like

```
sub num_last {
    my ($num_a, $num_b);
    my ($a,$b) = @_;
    ....
}
```

Than, you are really getting only first digit in a string **if the string starts from digit**. It's better add skipping all leading whitespaces, just in case.

```
($num_a) = $a =~ /^\s*(\d+)/;
($num_b) = $b =~ /^\s*(\d+)/;
```

`\d+` is equivalent to `[0-9]+`, but two chars shorter :). Braces force `list context` so, `$num_a` and `$num_b` receives content of first matched group: `(\d+)`.

Than, you don't need `<=>` opertor, as `$num_a` and `$num_b` should be strings, so you can simplify your condition to:

```
if (!$num_a)
    return -1;
if (!$num_b)   
    return 1;
return $a cmp $b;
```

Not sure, but it might be as simple as `return $a cmp $b`, but I'm not sure if empty var is stringwise lesser than non-empty string and no perl at fingertips. So, final num_last function:

```
sub num_last{
    my ($num_a, $num_b);
    my ($a,$b) = @_;

    ($num_a) = $a =~ /^\s*(\d+)/;
    ($num_b) = $b =~ /^\s*(\d+)/;

    if (!$num_a)
        return -1;
    if (!$num_b)   
        return 1;
    return $a cmp $b;
}
```

If you need reverse sort, just replace `my ($a,$b) = @_;` with `my ($b,$a) = @_;`

And, I've written it without any compiler help, so there might be some minor errors in it.

Comment: Subroutines used in conjunction with `sort` do not need to unpack `@_`. They can work directly with the package global variables `$a` and `$b`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html. Also your advice not to use `<=>` won't work well if the OP actually requires a numeric comparison.

Comment: thank you very much. I had sort the data.Now, I have problem with the operation in Perl. I want to write the operarion of excel: =MOD((AH4-AG4),3)+1 (the value of AH4=14185, AG4=13628). Could you show me how to write it with Perl?

Comment: I assume `MOD` is a modulo opearator. `my $a=14185; my $b=13628); my $rslt = (($a-$b)%3)+1`. Take a look at [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)